# Autoresize the root view when device is rotated

Tags: xcode, landscape, autoresize

I am developing PDF reader. I am facing problem while rotating the simulator. What I am doing is, when view is loaded by the `ViewController`(i.e. in the `loadView`), I am creating the `UIScrollView` which contains `UIImageView` and `UIView` of the same size(i.e. size of the PDF page). It is working perfectly in the portrait mode. But when I rotate the simulator in the landscape mode, the view is not autoresized according to device. I have tried

```
self.view.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

in the `viewDidLoad()` of the ViewController

But it's not working. I am confused how the above two properties work. I guess these properties will autoresize the `UIScrollView` to the size of root view in which I am loading `UIScrollView`. But what should be done to autoresize the main view in which UIScrollView is loaded??

Answer (score 0):

This is late reply... It may help if you didn't Fix it yet.

When you create any app in portraid mode and if you want it to rotate (resize) to landscape mode, you should do it in User Interface Builder or .xib (or in Storyboard iPad or iPhone)file.

So to check or to check rotate in the Simulator:

1. Go to "USER INTERFACE BUILDER", or ".XIB" (or "Storyboard iPad or iPhone") file.
2. Then select "UIImageView" and go to "SHOW THE ATTRIBUES INSPECTOR".
3. In the fourth tab (Attributes Inspector) set the mode to “Aspect Fit”, and in the third tab (Size Inspector) and in the fifth tab (Size Inspector) set the autosizing attributes to the following:

Set the arrows to all directions. Sorry can't load image.

1. Do the same for "UIView" (3).
2. Before you move on, you can double check that you’ve gotten all of the autosizing attributes right by selecting the Detail View Controller, and changing the orientation from Portrait to Landscape: Sorry can't load image for now...
3. You can Check or Change to "Landscape or Portrait" on the top right side "Simulated Metrics" select under "Size" the "Orientation".

If something isn’t right, don't worry: Just change it back to Portrait and double check the settings.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same problem when trying to utilise the auto resizing methods. So, I hope this will help. *(P.S. I'm assuming you're creating the UI programmatically and not via IB)*

So have you tried this?

**Inside your viewcontroller add the following:**

`// Set the View Controller to fit the whole screen.
-(BOOL)wantsFullScreenLayout{
    return YES;
}`

**Inside the loadView method amend your scrollView to:**

```
// set the initial size of your scrollView object.
[scrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

// Set the auto resizing attributes.
[scrollView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
```

*In addition to this you might need to set the autoresizingmask margins for either the UIView or UIImageView depending on the type of layout you require when the device is rotated.*